# menu items not showing on toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-menu

I have searched and found other as well with the same problem but still I could not resolve the issue of menu items not showing in the action bar. I will post my action bar code, menu_main.xml and `MainActivity`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PROJECT TIMELINE"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimaryDark" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

this is from menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />

</menu>
```

and I wrote this in MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: You should accept an answer if it answered your question

Comment: I extended ActionBarActivity and now it works! thanks

Comment: Oh yes.  You have to use either AppcompatActivity or ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialise the Toolbar and call this method in `onCreate` of your Activity

```
setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar);
```

Comment: but it is telling me that it cannot resolve this method, that's why I could not use it

Comment: What does your `MainActivity` extend?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you set your toolbar as the action bar. In your onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  setContentView(yourlayoutview);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  if (toolbar != null)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Make sure that you add an id to your toolbar:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PROJECT TIMELINE"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimaryDark" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using toolbar with navigation ui, make sure you call setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar) before  NavigationUI.setupWithNavController() else your toolbar buttons (mostly the back button) won't work.